# enter_set like behavior in TableEditor

Tags: enthought, traitsui

I'm building a `TableEditor` using the wx backend.  The table is a list of `DatasetElement` objects whose `panel_name` and `dataset_name` objects are exposed.  Additionally, and unrelated to the problem at hand, whatever row is selected additionally displays a more detailed view of that particular DatasetElement off to the right, using the `edit_view` attribute (this functionality makes the TableEditor desirable as opposed to some other view style).

I am listening to the 'panel_name' attribute and, whenever it changes, for instance updating two dictionaries for which the panel name is used for rapid lookup to relevant data about the panel.  This updates whenever a new character is typed into the display, so that I have two dictionaries who are constantly deleting the association `{'incomplete_wor':<DataObject>}` and replacing it with `{'incomplete_word':<DataObject>}` repeatedly as the new name is typed.

This isn't a serious problem, but is there a way to make the TableEditor update its list's members when the user hits enter or shifts the table selection, much like the `enter_set` keyword in a TextEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `ObjectColumn` to display/set your values you could specify an `editor` for that column. By specifying the editor to be `TextEditor` you can adjust the `enter_set` parameter as needed. Below is the example that would only update the value on ***Enter*** key press.

```
myTableEditor = TableEditor(columns=[
   ObjectColumn(name='panel_name', label='Panel Name'),
   ObjectColumn(name='dataset_name', label='Dataset Name', 
                editor=TextEditor(enter_set = True,
                                  auto_set  = False))
                                     ])
```

Hope this helps.